# Question about Picard group of $\mathbb{P}^1\times\mathbb{P}^1$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $Q=\mathbb{P}^1\times\mathbb{P}^1$. Denote by $p$, $q$ the projections on the components. Then $\text{Pic}\,Q$ is generated by $D_1$ and $D_2$, where $D_1=p^*x$, $D_2=q^*y$ and $x,y$ are points in $\mathbb{P}^1$. This might be a silly question but how can I compute the intersection numbers of these divisors?

Comment: One direct way is to use the Segre embedding.

Comment: Do you have a guess as to the result? Just asking....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intuitively, each copy of $\mathbb{P^1}$ sort of meet at one point, but each copy of $\mathbb{P^1}$ doesn't meet itself. So if you write $D = (a, b)$ and $D^\prime = (a^\prime, b^\prime)$ where the left and right coordinates stand for which copy of $\mathbb{P^1}$, then $D.D^\prime = a.b^\prime + b.a^\prime$.